# Bring Outside Java File Structure Into Java Program

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I would like to be able to add a file with the java structure and extension into my program to an arraylist via outside the actual program directory/jar.

Ex,

Test.java, located at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test.java (Outside the jar)

```
public class Test extends Object {

     public Test() {}

     public void someMethod() {}

}
```

MyProgram.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyProgram extends Object {

     public MyProgram() {}

     public void readIn() {

         ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
         list.add(Test.java);

     }

}
```

Obviously a lot more will have to be done but hopefully you understand the point.

Read In Test.java -> Convert it somehow so it's added to the arraylist due to it's extension. So if the extension was Family instead of Object, the arraylist would be ArrayList instead and Test extends Family.

Edit

As stated by a comment, this is an approach to a plugin mechanism.

Comment: Are you thinking of some _plugin_ mechanism? If not, I fear your question is unclear. Please try to give more details.

Comment: It's basically a plugin mechanism, you are correct. It was actually quite difficult to word such a question.

Comment: Then you really should learn about Java's built-in [service provider mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html).

Comment: You have to compile the Test.java file, then ensure you can access the class file on the classpath (or dynamically load it in)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I actually never heard of this, I'll look into it. Thanks a lot, if it works out I'll put this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question stems from Seelenvirtuose's suggestion along with crick_007. To access classes outside the class path, simply create a ClassLoader and load the class in. 
You must also use an interface to interact between the two classes, also knowing what methods are provided. Lastly, packaging must also be the same or else you'll get errors such as

PACKAGENAME.CLASS cannot be cast to PACKAGENAME.CLASS even if the class has the same name as in your program (A test I tried)